# Angularjs ui modal windows with timepicker

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to add a timepicker and a datepicker on a modal window and feels like the mytime model doesn't update. You can see it in the alert windows.

Can someone give me a hint. When I do a output on mytime in the model view the time doesn't show correct time compare to timepicker object.

Here is my sample code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/DUoyhB4VbhwUBAPWmUHD?p=preview

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Johnny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $modal service is creating a transclusion scope. You are bumping into a "classical" scoping issue which can be easily remedied by a famous "dot" in the ngModel expressions:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fnW36GBkJytAWEow9hpU?p=preview

Comment: Sorry to bring this question up, but why in the world, we need to enclose the timepicker into a div and set the ng-model to that div? If I don't use the DIV and set the ng-model to timepicker then nothing works? Ideas?